# How to automate the creation of Azure Databricks cluster using python script

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Is there any way to automate the creation of Azure Databricks Cluster creation using Python script

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I havent tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install any package, then you can use Databricks REST API directly, just define a payload, and call [create cluster API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/clusters/create). Something like this:

```py
import requests

workspace_host = "https://adb-.....azuredatabricks.net"
personal_token = "dapi...."

cluster_spec = {
    "cluster_name": "my-cluster",
    "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
    "spark_version": "11.3.x-scala2.12",
    "num_workers": 3
}

res = requests.post(workspace_host + "/api/2.0/clusters/create", 
   headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + personal_token}, 
   json=cluster_spec)
cluster_id = res.json()['cluster_id']
```

But it's better to use new [Databricks SDK for Python](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/) that simplifies many operations and supporting more authentication methods.

Comment: Is there any way that I can use my scripts in ARM template?

Comment: ARM templates are used to provision Azure infrastructure, but they aren't used for provisioning of resources inside the workspace. You can consider adoption of Terraform - the Databricks provider is very mature and much easier to use than REST API: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs. See also this repository for examples: https://github.com/databricks/terraform-databricks-examples